# Trying to detach a detachable handle on a meat grinder

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics

I'm trying to detach the handle from my meat grinder. I'm not sure what this kind of lock is called but it had a crescent/half moon shape that locks against the grinding (clockwise) motion. In order to detach it I would have to twist in the counterclockwise direction. But the thing is the piece the handle is attached to is the swirly metal piece and I'm not sure if I can stop that could lock it in place while I turn it counterclockwise. I tried putting the thing in the freezer but the lever also shrank with the semicircle locking part. I do get my hands on dry ice sometimes and I'm thinking that I could maybe use some gloves and put that in direct contact with the semicircle, but I'm wondering if that will somehow transfer the temperature over to the lever anyways since they're in direct contact with each other. If anyone knows the name of the locking mechanism that might help me google better. Thanks[image: the cursed beast]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the joint created by the handle and the auger bit is solid metal, the threading is, as you've noted, held in place by the rotation.

It is common that a sharp blow on the handle in the correct direction will cause the threads to release. Use a rubber mallet or wood mallet or other dead blow mallet, one that will not peen the metal in the handle and leave unsightly marks.

You may be able to combine the mallet method with a wrench applied to the semi-circle end, but you may create metal damage in so doing.